# draft state/publish changes on save in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I'm using angular 4 in my application and currently the user is able to make changes over multiple components(drag and drop, remove items, add items and etc...).

Now, for every user action there is a http requests via the relevant service that persist the changes on the DB.

There is a requirement that the user will be able to **make** this **changes and only persist them once he done changing and pressed save**. (it can be 10-50 actions from different types.)

How would you suggest refactoring the code in order to support that ? to make an array of user actions, and on save iterate over the array and make the relevant actions one by one, write some http middleware to hold all http calls until 'save' is pressed?

Comment: @Vega I do manage my separate forms in reactive style. but I don't see how this is relevant with multiple unrelated updates.

Comment: Does the db need to know all 50 things as separate actions before the user hit save?  Or is it okay to just save the final snapshot of the state and then ask the db to just record that?  For example assuming we have an array of items the user goes ahead and removes, reorders, and renames the items.  Instead of tracking each action you could just track the final item array result.

Comment: I have just added a usfull plunker example for you ..

Answer (score 1):

You should look into redux. This would allow a MVP programming model and works just fine with Angular. [ng2-redux](https://github.com/angular-redux/store)

Answer (score 1):

Just so you know the problem you are facing has a name.
"Application State Management"

This can be solved via redux like libraries (redux/ rxjs-store rxjs-effects etc)..

Or you could just use plain rxjs  `BehaviourSubject` or `Subject` as `Observable`.

here is a plunker example of using plain rxjs observables and angular services to achieve state management.
https://embed.plnkr.co/dEDJri4TziCS91oZiuHb/

TL;DR

**This is the services**

```
@Injectable()
export class AppStateService{

  private _dataSaved = new Subject<string>();
  public dataSaved$ = this._dataSaved.asObservable()
  constructor() {}

  dispatchSaveEvent(data: String){
    this._dataSaved.next(data);
  }
}
```

**This is the component that will dispatch the save event**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-footer',
  template: `
    <button (click)="saveData($event)">Save</button>
  `
})
export class Footer implements OnInit {
  constructor(private appState: AppStateService) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  saveData(e){
    this.appState.dispatchSaveEvent("Some data to save here...");

  }
}
```

**This is how you consume the observable in every component that is interested that a saved has occurred**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-comp-1',
  template: `
    <h1>Component-1! {{savedDataRecived}}</h1>
  `
})
export class Comp1 implements OnInit {
   savedDataRecived = "";

  constructor(private appState: AppStateService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.appState.dataSaved$.subscribe(data=> this.handleSaveEvent(data))
  }

  handleSaveEvent(data: string){
    this.savedDataRecived = data;
  }
}
```